# YII2 OAuth Client Instagram - Instagram drops "authclient=instagram" when redirecting

Tags: oauth, yii2, instagram

i'm using yii2 oauthclinet extension kotchuprik/yii2-instagram-authclient

so its working fien but one thing ist not working

i registered in instagram my app redirurl like that

```
myappurl/site/auth?authclient=instagram
```

so the redirecturl i expected should be like that:

```
myappurl/site/auth?authclient=instagram&code=....
```

but it comes:

```
myappurl/site/auth?code=...
```

using developer tools in browser i recognize:

```
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/

username=myusernam
password=mypassword
queryParams={"next":"/oauth/authorize?client_id=theclientid&   
response_type=code&redirect_uri=myappurl/site/auth?authclient=instagram&
xoauth_displayname=MyApps&state=statenumbers"}
```

so here is it ok the next get request is wrong

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=theclientid&
response_type=code&redirect_uri=myappurl%2Fsite%2Fauth%3Fauthclient&
xoauth_displayname=MyApps&state=statenumbers

client_id=theclientid
response_type=code
redirect_uri=myappurls%2Fsite%2Fauth%3Fauthclient
xoauth_displayname=MyApp
state=statenumbers
```

here is the =instagram gone

the redirected url from instagram is then:

```
myappurl/site/auth?code=codenumbers&state=statenumbers
```

so this ist wrong the authclient=instagram is gone lost, i dont know why

any ideas?

Comment: you need to add the parameter `authclient` to your action  if i get it correctly, currently the `actionAuth` inside the `SiteController` would be like `function actionAuth($codenumber,$state)` , correct ?

Comment: i integrate the authAction like in Yii2 Docs:
    'auth' => [
                'class' => '\common\components\AuthAction', //'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' =...

if authclient came as parameter comes back its working fine. The problem i dont know why the return url from instagram is without this parameter. if i call the auth action again, then the return url is correkt and the sign in / login are working fine. 
But where or why i get the return url without autclient. i cant find the place, where this parameter dropping happens.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little workaround, not realy pretty, but working.

```
`class AuthAction extends \yii\authclient\AuthAction
{

public function run()
{
$clientId = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam($this->clientIdGetParamName);
if (!empty($clientId)) {
    $collection = Yii::$app->get($this->clientCollection);
    if (!$collection->hasClient($clientId)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Unknown auth client '{$clientId}'");
    }
    $client = $collection->getClient($clientId);

    return $this->auth($client);
} else {
    $clientId = 'instagram';
    $collection = Yii::$app->get($this->clientCollection);
    if (!$collection->hasClient($clientId)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Unknown auth client '{$clientId}'");
    }
    $client = $collection->getClient($clientId);

    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['/site/auth','authclient'=>'instagram']);

}

 // throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
}`
```

so i think that instagram recognized that on this device a instagram user is logged in and the return not the defined or expected url with  authclient parameter. Or its a Instagram bug :-).

may if someone has similar problems, would be great thats to here thats more people are infected by this problem. So may we can get a solution.